# Generate content formed by multiple URLs with for loop

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a dynamic mixin to create a preloader for my images. The upper part that generate the classes works well, but the lower part won't.

This is the code:

```sass
$n: 5;
$step: 100 / $n;

@keyframes logo-bg-change {
    @for $i from 0 to $n {
        $current-frame: $step * $i;

        #{$current-frame}% {
            background-image: url('../images/logo-bg/bg#{$i + 1}.jpg');
        }
    }
}

@mixin preload-content($cycles) {
    $content: '';

    @for $i from 0 to $n {
        $content: $content + ' ' + url('../images/logo-bg/bg#{$i + 1}.jpg');
    }

    content: $content;
}

body:after {
    display: none;
    @include preload-content($n);
}
```

The result of the bottom part is:

```css
body: after {
    display: none;
    content: ' url("../images/logo-bg/bg1.jpg") url("../images/logo-bg/bg2.jpg") url("../images/logo-bg/bg3.jpg") url("../images/logo-bg/bg4.jpg") url("../images/logo-bg/bg5.jpg")';
}
```

But it should be:

```css
body:after {
    display: none;
    content:
        url('../images/logo-bg/bg1.jpg')
        url('../images/logo-bg/bg2.jpg')
        url('../images/logo-bg/bg3.jpg')
        url('../images/logo-bg/bg4.jpg')
        url('../images/logo-bg/bg5.jpg');
}
```

Is there a way to chain URLs tags as tags and not as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list instead using the `append()` function.

```
@mixin preload-content($cycles) {
    $content: ();

    @for $i from 0 to $n {
        $content: append($content, url('../images/logo-bg/bg#{$i + 1}.jpg'));
    }

    content: $content;
}
```